# Is there way to throw via custom System.Management.Automation.ErrorRecord?

Tags: powershell

I'd like to throw custom `System.Management.Automation.ErrorRecord` with some additional properties: `ContextMessage` and `SqlCmdHeader`.

I tried to create new class inherited from `System.Management.Automation.ErrorRecord`:

```bsh
class SqlRequestException : System.Management.Automation.ErrorRecord
{
    [hashtable]$SqlCmdHeader

    [string]$ContextMessage

    SqlRequestException() { }

    SqlRequestException(
        [string]$message,
        [hashtable]$sqlCmdHeader,
        [System.Management.Automation.ErrorRecord]$errorRecord
    ) : base($errorRecord, $null)
    {
        $this.SqlCmdHeader = $sqlCmdHeader
        $this.ContextMessage = $message
    }
}
```

But when I throw the error by this code:

```bsh
try
{
    #exceptions is risen here
}
catch
{
    throw ([SqlRequestException]::New(
            "Some context message of exception which will help to understand the error without additional debugging of code",
            $sqlHeader,
            $_))
}
```

I got in caller just `System.Management.Automation.ErrorRecord` without my awesome properties. Looks like `throw` cast my object to `System.Management.Automation.ErrorRecord` and lost the properties.

I'd like to ask you guys to help me to implement this logic in my script. Any help will be much appreciate!

### Update

I'm not able to change caller's code. It always parses error and write it to logs:

```bsh
try
{
    # calling the method from module where I try to throw custom ErrorRecord
}
catch
{
    Write-Log -Text $_
}
```

I cannot use `System.Exception` because when I throw created exception, all original information (such as `InvocationInfo`, `ScriptStackTrace` and etc) from `ErrorRecord` is lost. I couldn't find source code of `throw` statement to understand how exactly it works (maybe someone can point me to it?)

I see there is `TargetObject` property which could be used to store some additional information, but I don't see ways to put something to the property before `throw` statement since the property is `ReadOnly` and I think the property is not designed to store additional user's data.

Answer (score 2):

While the [`System.Management.Automation.ErrorRecord`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-US/dotnet/api/System.Management.Automation.ErrorRecord) class isn't technically sealed and the documentation doesn't mention subclassing, **it looks like subclassing `ErrorRecord` is effectively *not supported***:

As you've experienced, the original `SqlRequestException` instance you `throw` doesn't make it as such up the call stack, *presumably* because copying into an instance of the base class is involved.

**Subclass `System.Exception` instead** and let PowerShell automatically wrap your exception in an `[ErrorRecord]` instance whose `.Exception` property you can later query:

```
# Make your custom exception derive from System.Exception.
class SqlRequestException : System.Exception
{
    [hashtable]$SqlCmdHeader
    [string]$ContextMessage

    # Construct the exception with the one passed as an 
    # argument as the *inner* exception.
    SqlRequestException(
        [string]$contextMessage,
        [hashtable]$sqlCmdHeader,
        [exception]$innerException
    ) : base($innerException.Message, $innerException)
    {
        $this.ContextMessage = $contextMessage
        $this.SqlCmdHeader = $sqlCmdHeader
    }
}

try { # Outer `try` to simulate a caller.
  try # Your code.
  {
      [int]::Parse('not a number') # Sample exception.
  }
  catch
  {
     # Throw your custom exception that wraps the original exception
     # ($_.Exception) via its .InnerException property.
     # PowerShell itself then automatically wraps your custom exception in
     # an [ErrorRecord] instance.
     throw ([SqlRequestException]::New(
              'custom message',
              @{ header1 = 'foo' },
              $_.Exception))
  }
} catch { # The (simulated) caller's catch block.
  # Now you can access your custom properties via $_.Exception.
  @"
Error: $_
Custom properties:
  ContextMessage: $($_.Exception.ContextMessage)
  SqlCmdHeader: $($_.Exception.SqlCmdHeader | Out-String)
"@
}
```

The above yields the following, showing that both custom properties were passed through:

```
Error: Exception calling "Parse" with "1" argument(s): "Input string was not in a correct format."
Custom properties:
  ContextMessage: custom message
  SqlCmdHeader: 
Name                           Value
----                           -----
header1                        foo
```

The custom exception's message is that of the original exception; to get the details of the original exception, access `$_.InnerException`.

Comment: @AceLightning: To clarify: the update mostly does what you want, except that the original exception is now the `.InnerException` of your custom exception, though the message is the original's. If this is not sufficient, please provide feedback.

Answer (score 0):

You can create Custom object in catch block(you dont need own class), something like this.

```
$customobj = New-Object -TypeName psobject 
$customobj | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name SQLhead -Value $sqlHeader 
$customobj | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name Error -Value $_
```

A bit more about create custom object [custom objects](https://www.gngrninja.com/script-ninja/2016/6/18/powershell-getting-started-part-12-creating-custom-objects)

Answer (score 0):

I once had to do something quite similar.

first, I had to transform my function into a Cmdlet to gain access to `$PSCmdlet.ThrowTerminatingError` and build my own `[system.management.automation.errorrecord]`.

the caller have most of the information in `$PSItem` in the `catch` block but the inner details are hidden. if inner details are needed, they can be accessed via `$PSItem.Exception.ComplementaryInfo` and `$PSItem.Exception.ErrorRecord`

adapted to your question it would look like the following code. but if the caller's `catch` block can only be `Write-Log -Text $_`, this will be of no help.

```
class myException: system.exception
{
    [System.Management.Automation.ErrorRecord]$ErrorRecord
    $ComplementaryData

    myException(
        [System.Management.Automation.ErrorRecord]$ErrorRecord,
        $ComplementaryData
    ) : base($errorRecord.Exception.message,$errorRecord.exception)
    {
            $this.ErrorRecord       = $ErrorRecord
            $this.ComplementaryData = $ComplementaryData
    }
}

function doSomething {
    [CmdletBinding()]
    param( )

    try
    {
        [int]::Parse('not a number') # Sample exception.
    }
    catch
    {
        $PSCmdlet.ThrowTerminatingError(
            [system.management.automation.errorrecord]::new(
                [myException]::new($PSItem,'some more data'),
                $PSItem.FullyQualifiedErrorId,
                $PSItem.CategoryInfo.Category,
                $PSItem.TargetObject
            )
        )
    }
}


# caller's code
try
{ 
    DoSomething
}
catch
{
    Write-Host -ForegroundColor Red $_ # to simulate Write-Log -Text $_

    # you can access your complementary data + info from the original ErrorRecord
    $PSItem.Exception.ComplementaryData
    $PSItem.Exception.ErrorRecord.InvocationInfo
    $PSItem.Exception.ErrorRecord.ScriptTrace
}
```